# yii efullcalendar widget and external events drag and drop not working

Tags: yii, fullcalendar, yii-extensions

Hi I am trying to use drag and drop external events for fullcalendar and get working with the yii extension full calender - which seems to be just a wrapper.

The part that is not working (no errors just does not work) is dragging the external event onto the calendar and it staying there. It drags over but it just returns home.

Reading the fullcalendar docs - it looks like I need to provide a callback function to 'drop' attribute. I've been using the external-event example which is part of full calendar. I did discover the example was using the object name '#calendar' and that yii is creating name '#yw0' but it still didn't work after I updated.

I cannot find a way to get it work. I tried a simple alert which sort of works, it is called on page load - not after a drag operation.

So I declared a variable with the function in View

```
//$dropcallback=new CJavaScriptExpression("alert('hi')");
$dropcallback=new CJavaScriptExpression(
     "function(date, allDay) {
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
        $('#yw0').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
           // if so, remove the element from the Draggable Events list
           $(this).remove();
        }
     }
  ");
```

Then I create the widgit like this

```
$this->widget('ext.EFullCalendar.EFullCalendar', array(
'themeCssFile'=>'cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css',
'options'=>array(
    'header'=>array(
        'left'=>'prev,next',
        'center'=>'title',
        'right'=>'today'
    ),
    'editable'=>true,
    'dropable'=>true,
    'drop'=>$dropcallback,
    'events'=>Game::model()->gameCalendarData(),
)));
```

My yii experiance is little and same with JS - so any help appreciated in how to get this working.

I understand that in JS you need to provide a callback to allow the drag op to succeed. But what sort of call back do I need when it is wrapped in a yii widgit? I tried a PHP callback and again it is only called on page load.

The result I wish is that I can build the external events list from the DB - allow users to drag them onto the calendar - and save them in the DB.

I did manage to get data from DB displayed in the calendar.

Thanks

Comment: javascript files in asset folder of the widget is out dated, you probably need to get the latest scripts and replace the old ones

Comment: Looking through asset files - jquery is indeed old FullCalendar v1.6.4, jQuery v1.8.3. If I delete the asset folder - it comes back again but I do not know where it is getting jquery from. FC changelog has newer versions of jquery - but newest line says `"use bower internally for fetching new versions of jQuery and jQuery UI"` - so attempting to install bower

Comment: not assets of your app, scripts of the calender extension, in there look for it

Comment: The extension uses the yii jquery - I found to update config scriptMap to use newer jquery - a typo was my problem - thanks for looking though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Droppable is spelt with two p's. So

```
'dropable'=>true,
```

Should be

```
'droppable'=>true,
```